# Transaction Firebase mutableData always null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to send a transaction to my firebase database however the mutableData in the doTransaction is always printing null. From what I researched it can do this sometimes but all I should have to do is allow it to be null and it should find the correct value on a different retry. Below is my code:

```
MainActivity.secondaryDatabase.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
            @Override
            public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData mutableData) {
                System.out.println(mutableData.getValue());
                if(mutableData.getValue() != null){
                    if(mutableData.child("UsingFileBool").getValue(String.class).equals("True")){
                        return Transaction.abort();
                    }
                    else{
                        mutableData.child("UsingFileBool").setValue("True");
                        return Transaction.success(mutableData);
                    }
                }
                return Transaction.success(mutableData);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(committed){
                    commitChanges.set(true);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(databaseError);
                    commitChanges.set(false);
                }
            }
        });
```

The resulting output is:

```
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: null
I/System.out: DatabaseError: The transaction had too many retries
```

But with more null outputs than i cared to copy and paste cause I think you get the point.

I also have attached a Listener to my database on startup of the app which prints the child count of the database (1) correctly but the transaction prints (0) constantly.

```
public void addListenerToEditingFirebase(){
    secondaryDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            MainActivity.editingDatabase = dataSnapshot;
            System.out.println("Child Count: " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    });
}
```

Btw, my Firebase database is:

```
EditingFile{
    UsingFileBool: "False"
}
```

Comment: It is expected that your `doTransaction` will be called with `null` initially in many cases, and indeed your code needs to be able to handle that situation. What is the problem with the code you shared?

Comment: It always returns null and then i get a database error saying its run too many times.

Comment: The first time it may be passing in an empty `MutableSnapshot` that has a value `null` that doesn't come from the database, but the second time it is most certainly a value that comes from the database. If you get `null` then, there really is no value at `MainActivity.secondaryDatabase`.

Comment: Thanks for your help dude, i just had to change the runTransaction line to MainActivity.secondaryDatabase.child("UsingFileBool").runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {